# Replace multiple occurrences in the same line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ to replace some lines. Basically what I want to do is:

line 1 -

```
STR::P=FOOXPATTERN=5 AND MORETHINGS YPATTERN=9 BUT XPATTERN=3 AND YPATTERN=20
```

line 2 -

```
MOR::P=BAR XPATTERN=1 STRSTR MORETHINGS YPATTERN=1BUT XPATTERN=10 AND YPATTERN=40
```

...

So this must be transformed in:

line 1

```
XPATTERN=5|YPATTERN=9|PATTERN=3|YPATTERN=20
```

line 2 -

```
XPATTERN=1|YPATTERN=1|XPATTERN=10|YPATTERN=40
```

My point is that I can have many XPATTERN and many YPATTERN in the same line. Then I would like to replace all my line for the pattern found.

I tried to use negation on regex, but with no success.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60012019/edit) and add real values for `XPATTERN` & `YPATTERN` in a real test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^|\G(?!^)).*?((?:XPATTERN|YPATTERN)=\d+)(?:(?!(?:XPATTERN|YPATTERN)=).)*($)?`
- Replace with: `$1(?2:|))`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                     # non capture group
    ^                       # beginning of line
  |                       # OR
    \G(?!^)                 # restart from last match position, not at the beginning of line
)                       # end group
.*?                     # 0 or more any character but newline
(                       # group 1
    (?:                     # non capture group
        XPATTERN                # XPATTERN
      |                       # OR
        YPATTERN                # YPATTERN
    )                       # end group
    =\d+                    # equal sign followed by 1 or more digits
)                       # end group 1
(?:                     # non capture group
    (?!                     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after:
        (?:                     # non capture group
            XPATTERN                # XPATTERN
          |                       # OR
            YPATTERN                # YPATTERN
        )                       # end group
        =                       # equal sign
    )                       # end lookahead
    .                       # any character but newline
)*                      # end group, may appear 0 or more times
($)?                    # group 1, end of line, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1 (i.e. X or Y PATTERN = digits)
(?2             # IF group 2 exists (end of line), do nothing
    :           # ELSE
    |           # add a pipe character
)               # ENDIF
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: @downvoter: Really nice your downvote, is there any reason?

Comment: I never understood these people!

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp that matches the pattern and anything before it, and replaces it with just the pattern.

Replace: `.*?((XPATTERN|YPATTERN|ZPATTERN|...)=\d+)`
With: `|\1`

If there's something after all the patterns, you can remove the rest after the above replacements with:

Replace: `^((\|(XPATTERN|YPATTERN|ZPATTERN|...)=\d+)*).*`
With: `\1`

This will leave a `|` at the beginning of each line. You can remove that as a third step:

Replace: `^\|`
With: empty string

Comment: I wrote YPATTERN and XPATTERN for better understanding. Actually in each line I have two different patterns like....**ZBR_4540XX::** and **OOPP400X!!**

Comment: something like.../(xpattern=\d|ypattern=\d*)/

Comment: WOW. It's almost perfect, thank you! but I forgot to mention that can be more string in the end of the line. I swear that I try to do it, but couldln`t. Can you show me?

Comment: That makes it harder. This would be much easier in a programming language than a text editor.